How fix gradlew not running?
I can't run ./graldew install in any of my projects.
I tried creating new projects and upgrading gradle, but it didn't resolve my issue.
my build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}


android {
    namespace = "com.arzhangap.test"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.arzhangap.test"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

Project Gradle JDK version: 17
Gradle version: 8.7
Gradle Plugin version: 8.5.2
I also have set JAVA_HOME version to 17.
Error message after running ./gradlew install:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')


I've tried different jdk versions, but it didn't resolve my issue.

Any reason you're not using the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin, which is 8.6.1? It does seem that 8.5.2 is not compatible with Java 17, though you should still be able to decrease JVM target level to 8 to get it to work.

Welcome to StackOverflow! We're excited to have you in the community—happy coding!
